# Не могу установить .NET Framework 3.5 на windows 8.1

Tags: windows, framework

Не могу установить `.NET Frameworker 3.5` на Windows 8.1 . Диска с установщиком нет, включить в компонентах не получается. Скачал его с сайта Майкрософт, пытался установить и не вышло, так как он запросил сам себя.
Установить по запросу не получается. Что делать?

Comment: Забить на win8 потому что даже майки признали, что что-то пошло не так?

Comment: Что именно происходит, когда включаете в компонентах? Комп случайно не в домене с собственным wsus?